# What happened actually in the game Kreschmer - Laue, Aisenach 1951?

Tags: history, middlegame, famous-games

```
[Title "Kretschmar vs. Laue, 1951"]
[fen "7k/3R2pq/pb3N2/1p4Qp/5p2/1PP2P1P/1P4PK/4r3 w - - 0 1"]
```

In a German book, Spass am Kombinieren (*Joy of Combination*) by Albin Pötzsch, it is claimed that White played h4 and lost to Rh1 with mate to follow. It was also mentioned that Qc5!! would have won. Other sources claim that White played Qc5 !! I wonder what was actually played.

The whole game would be nice. Who knows a reference?

Comment: Can you tell us which "book" and which "other sources" it is where you found this funny position ? FWIW, I can't find this game on chessgames.com

Comment: Albin Pötzsch - Spass am Kombinieren (a german book) claims that White lost with h4

Comment: Not found a source or a better reference ... yet.  However, I have found the position published as "White can capture Nxh7 but passes up the opportunity. Was this a mistake? If it was, what did he play instead?' and Qc5 is given as the answer.  The h4 move is not even mentioned. However, this dates from 1998, so it is still far from the supposed date of origin. It may still be an analysis, rather than real game, though.

Comment: @Peter I find the spelling of "Aisenach" weird. Is that how it is written in the book? A German author would very likely have used "Eisenach". The correct spelling of the name of Laue's opponent should almost certainly be "Kretschmar", by the way -- in 1951 German corr. players met over-the-board in Eisenach, and both Laue and Kretschmar played in the "hauptturnier".

Answer (score 1):

The only reference I can find is from Chess.com - India. They claim that Kretschmar found the win. On [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/chesscom.in/posts/in-this-chaotic-position-white-crafted-a-perfect-end-with-a-thrilling-move-can-y/1618727681814499/), [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/CbFLXsvhAwf/) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/chesscom_in/status/1503287316697149446?lang=en) they posted the position with this question:

> In this chaotic position, White crafted a perfect end with a thrilling move. Can you find the end?

So, they are saying that White found Qc5! but they don't give the full game.

The best response they got was on Twitter. Here is some analysis:

```
[Title "Kretschmar vs. Laue, 1951"]
[fen "7k/3R2pq/pb3N2/1p4Qp/5p2/1PP2P1P/1P4PK/4r3 w - - 0 1"]

1. Qc5! {Stops perpetual and wins massive material or checkmate} Bxc5 (1...gxf6 2. Qf8+ Qg8 3. Qxf6+ Qg7 4. Qxg7#) (1... Re8 2. Rxg7 Qg6 (2...Kxg7 3. Nxe8+ Kf7 4. Nd6+ Kg8 5. Qxb6) 3. Rxg6 Bxc5 4. Nxe8 Kh7 5. Rxa6) 2. Rd8+ Re8 3. Rxe8+ Bf8 4. Rxf8+ Qg8 5. Rxg8#
```